# Python :error'list' object has no attribute 'sorted'

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
#这是一个有关旅行的程序
place=['北京天安门','西安兵马俑','香港游乐园','日本秋叶原']
print(place)
print(sorted(place))
print(place)

place.sorted(reverse=true)
print(place)
```

When I run my code, something Wrong happens.

```
place.sorted(reverse=true)
```

or

```
sorted(place)
```

---

Using the 2nd way, how can I give `(reverse=true)`?

Comment: It's either `sorted` (not inplace) or `list.sort` (which is inplace)`. In both cases they accept a `reverse` keyword argument.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  - you could have solved this by yourself quite easily by reading the error message and the documentation, or even just googling for "python list sort reverse"

Comment: In python ,True & true is not different ?? I think True is correct .thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `sorted(place, reverse=True)`.

Comment: Thank you verymuch!  It is my mistik ,my true is true.Now  i know the true is True.